# dbus systemd service not auto starting

Tags: systemd, dbus

I am trying to start a service which use dbus.

Basically, this is flask server proxying requests to dbus.

I have created a systemd file like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=...

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/root/api.py
Type=dbus
BusName=com.api

[Install]
WantedBy=dbus.service
Also=graphical.target
```

When ever i restart the device, the service will be dead(inactive) but if i open a terminal and start it (`systemctl start api`) , it works fine.
It would seem my install section is wrong, though i don't see why, as dbus is wanted and graphical target should  be sufficient.

Is there something obvious i am missing?

Comment: This probably a question of one of the Linux forums where is looks like this has been answer already: https://askubuntu.com/a/733510

Comment: Sadly the answers found (including that one) does not help me, as i already enabled the service and checked the symlinks is present.
Though i will try a linux forum instead :)

Comment: Have you checked the output with `journalctl`, which stores all the system’s log messages. If I were to speculate, I would think `WantedBy=dbus.service` should be `Requires=dbus.service` or `Wants=dbus.service`